# ORA-00918 in view with unique column names

Tags: oracle

Why i have error with vtemp, but vtemp2 works?
There is no duplicate column names in my view.
And same column name works in where clause and didn't work in select

```
create table temp1 (i1 int, j1 int);
insert into temp1 values( 1,1); 
create table temp2 (i2 int, j2 int);
insert into temp2 values( 1,1); 
create view vtemp as select * from temp1 join temp2 on i1 = i2;

select i1 from vtemp;
--works as expected
select * from vtemp where i2 = 1;
--works as expected
select i2 from vtemp;
--ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
```

And if i create equivalent view error disappears

```
create view vtemp2 as select t1.*, t2.* from temp1 t1 join temp2 t2 on i1 = i2;
select i2 from vtemp2;
--works as expected
```

Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bi

Comment: Not able to [reproduce this issue](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3fa0a2ec209b91b1d2bb8b2a17881ede) (this is a 11g fiddle but I would expect the same behavior in 10g).

Comment: Side note: there is no `vtemp2` in your sql script.

Comment: @GMB there is, it just wasn't formatted correctly.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if that is one of the many bugs that 9i and 10i contained regarding the JOIN operator. Does it work if you use the ancient implicit joins?

Comment: If i create view as "create view vtemp as select * from temp1,  temp2 where i1 = i2;" everything work fine.